# Steering wheel vs Gamepad - angle of wheels

Tags: controllers

When using a keyboard to play racing games, you press the right or left arrow key, and the wheels turn all the way to the left or right, and when you release the key, they move to their original position (straight). There's no way to hold them at a particular position like you could when using a steering wheel. Is it the same way when using a game pad? or can I hold the wheels at a particular angle when using a gamepad?

Comment: This probably depends on the game, and how it processes input. What game in particular are you asking about?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Test Drive Unlimited 2 and Need for Speed Hot Pursuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every racing game I've played lately (NFS: Hot Pursuit, Burnout: Paradise, driving in FPS/RPG games) I've been able to hold the wheels at specific angles with the gamepad. I refuse to use the keyboard for racing games for precisely that reason. In some older games which were never designed to be used with anything but a keyboard, it may be just a right/left thing, but I think any modern game will have this feature.

Comment: Shall but one and try. Lets see how it goes.

Comment: Paradise is a lot of fun, I'd definitely recommend it. Hot Pursuit is fun too, but not the same. There's no fun in freeroam.